# Chrome extension, message to content script of newly created tab only works with alert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension that takes the url from the current tab and puts it in a field  in a newly opened tab.
The field in the new tab seems to only be filled when there's an alert before sending the message. Probably because of asynchronicity, howewer I do sendMessage in the callback function of the creation of the tab.

Here is my background.js:

```
function sendMessage(msg) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg);
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        var tabURL = tab.url;

        chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://..<url>.."}, function(tab) {
            alert(''); //<- it only seems to work with this alert in it.
            sendMessage(tabURL);
        });
    });
});
```

And my content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender) {
        document.getElementById('field').value = request;
});
```

Comment: Is the correct parameter being passed into `sendMessage`? Remove the alert and set a breakpoint inside `sendMessage` and see what the value of `msg` is (I think it will be undefined).

Comment: My guess is you have a race condition where you are sending the message before the content script is loaded. Try storing the URL in memory in the background and when the content script loads, have it ask the background script for the URL.

Comment: @berrberr: if I put the tabURL variable in the alert, it shows indeed the URL. Also the URL appears in the field in the new tab. Also, if I set the variable first, outside of the method, there's still nothing in the field. My guess is that somehow the message is send before the creation of the new tab has finished (even though I'm using the callback function).
Sorry, couldn't perform your test as I don't know yet how to debug here.

Comment: @abraham: that might work, though it sounds a bit dirty and not the way you would want it. So that would work with sending a message from content.js, receiving it with a listener in background.js and then sending the data from the background?

Comment: @bvoerle yep. You could also play around with [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) to know when the tab has finished loading.

Comment: @berrberr: Found the debugger :-); the tabURL variable has the correct value, so it must be something like my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks to abraham:

Made tabURL a global var:

```
var tabURL = '';
```

Removed callback function from chrome.tabs.create:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://..<url>.."});
```

Added onUpdated listener to background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    sendMessage(tabURL);
});
```